# Running proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com as root

Tags: command-line, xfce4-terminal

i am getting an error *Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported* while running the command [`proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com`](https://github.com/haad/proxychains) on terminal.

What to do?

Comment: Firefox is trying to warn you that you would be doing something destructive to your operating system if you continue. Do what the error message says and don't run Firebox as root, otherwise soon you will need to reinstall Ubuntu.